# Requiring more than just a programming language tag before an answer is accepted

Tags: feature-request, tags

Since Stack Overflow is centered around programming language-related questions we know that the programming language tags are by far the most effective and necessary tag to get an answer. This is very effective for new users and easy to understand.

Now for us more experienced users who do searches for previous questions before answering existing questions or posting new questions, it is far more efficient and faster to search based on tags than words because one may only need to search for one or two tags in addition to the programming language tag, and can check for other tags in the list or look at the tags of similar questions to see what tags the community are using. While if one searches for words in the Q&A one not only has to search many more words, but also hope to have covered all of the possible words and phrases that cover the question.

The way I commonly view tags is as a hierarchy of terms used to narrow down to a specific area, like the [Dewey Decimal System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification) for a library, but using tags instead of numbers.

If questions with only a programming language tag are required to have more than just the programming language tag it increases the chance of finding more relevant questions when searching with tags. With better results when searching for duplicate questions or similar questions leads to a better site.

It is not uncommon for me with [f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23) to suspect a question is a duplicate, but being unable to find it with just a tag search. Then upon finding the duplicate see that an obvious tag was not included. This often happens, because new users don't know what tags to use and often ask the same question, but in a different guise.

As such I would like to recommend, that before a question can receive an accept vote, that if the only tag is a programming language tag that another tag must be added for further classification. The reason for placing the constraint on the accepted answer is because many new users do not know what tags to use, but the person answering typically does know what additional tags are relevant. Also since 2,000 reputation points is required to [edit a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), additionally I recommend that anyone answering a question have the right to edit only the tags for the corresponding question.

### TL;DR

In searching for duplicate or related questions I searched for
`[tags] minimum`
`[tags] recommend`
`[site-recommendation] [tags]`
`[related-questions] [tags]`
`[tag-search]`
`[tag-tips]`
`[suggested-tags]`

If this is a duplicate question, please let me know...

### The other Meta Q or A of interest to this question:

*[Should some tags “warn” users before posting? - Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253678/1243762)*

> Compromise: It may be possible to require extra confirmation from
>   low-reputation or new users, and then stop requiring such as soon as
>   they reach some reputation line.

I find this of interest because in a related manner it suggests that new users can be required to add more tags and once they have enough reputation points avoid the extra step. IIRC, currently additional tags are only suggested.

*[Do we need to force any questions tagging assembly to tag the architecture also?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287800/1243762)*

> Many questions are incorrectly tagged simply because the person asking
>   doesn't know any better (either in the technology they're using or
>   they don't fully understand how the site works). Some of those people
>   will be first semester students at some random college/university and
>   will be crapping themselves about the subject they've got themselves
>   in to.

I find this of interest because it reaffirms that many question OP are not effective at tagging their own questions.

*[Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632/1243762)*

[image]

I find this interesting, because I don't recall seeing such a pop up dialog for a specific tag, but a dialog could be used as part of this recommendation. I tend to hang out on the fringes, e.g. [f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23), [prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog), [compiler-construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-construction), where the ethos are more homegrown.

*[Search results incorrect for F#](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268936/1243762)*

> When you search for just C# it gets converted in a tag search because
>   the SE search engine is programmed to treat the search string as a tag
>   when a search string is one of the top 60 tags of the SE site. C# is
>   in the top tag list whereas F# is not, so it is treated as a regular
>   search.

Learned something new about searching and tags.

### Meta SO tags

[image]

I find this of interest because it shows that requirements can be placed on tags.

Comment: Aside from the technical challenges of implementing this, I'd expect more bad things than good things to come out of this, with users just picking a random tag to make the system shut up and let them post their question already.

Comment: @Stijn Thanks for the feedback. I plan to leave the question posted so that others who have the same idea can see what the community thinks. :)

Comment: Accept votes don't have anything whatsoever to do with tags.

Comment: Perhaps a machine learning algorithm could try to infer tags not only from question content, but also related tags -- and suggest them? This should however only be additional information provided, not a requirement to post questions. This is very often a problem for me e.g. in Math, that I don't know ex-ante what other tags this could relate to, but if I find them suggested, I know whether or not that tag is applicable.

Answer (score 3):

> The way I commonly view tags is as a hierarchy of terms used to narrow
>   down to a specific area, like the Dewey Decimal System for a library,
>   but using tags instead of numbers.

This is, to my eye, the major flaw with your idea here: the tag system isn't inherently hierarchical. In *some cases* the applicable tags may happen to work out that way, but it's not an assumption of the system, so you shouldn't be applying that expectation to all questions.

Further, the reason we allow (almost) anyone to edit (almost) any post is a recognition that a post doesn't have to be perfect to be posted. If you see a question that you think could benefit from additional tagging, you can and should edit to add the appropriate tags. That said, there's plenty of decent posts, this one included, that only start out with one tag - and many that only really need one.

Comment: I was wondering when someone would note that I only put one tag on this. :) Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Why then require at least one tag to be added, if a question does not have to be perfect to be posted? That such a minimum exists in the first place indicates that some quality threshold already exists for tags, so your line of argument is not valid, as it would lead to dropping the minimum of 1 tag if applied consistently.

Comment: @tkruse - a question is expected to be related to **something**.  If a poster can't come up with a single tag that relates to their question, that's a pretty surefire guarantee that it's not an on topic question. I wasn't arguing that that should change, and I'm not sure why you're implying that I was. I was just drawing focus to the notion that all posts are fair game for editing to improve them, which is a core tenet of this site.

Comment: The more important part of my answer, though, is the assertion that the asker is incorrect in their supposition that tags are inherently hierarchical. That notion works in some cases, but certainly not all.

Comment: I was only commenting on the less important part of your question, I don't think it strengthens your answer. Reviewer time is more valuable than time of the one writing the question, whatever burden can be shifted from the former to the latter is a good change.

Comment: The second part follows from the first, though - because it's not always true that there'll be a more specific tag that's appropriate, it doesn't make sense to enforce it as a requirement. Instead, we trust askers to use their best judgement, and allow editing for cases where they miss something.